# How to get data returned from fetch() promise?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am having trouble wrapping my head around returning json data from a fetch() call in one function, and storing that result in a variable inside of another function. Here is where I am making the fetch() call to my API:

```
function checkUserHosting(hostEmail, callback) {
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/activities/' + hostEmail)
    .then((response) => { 
        response.json().then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    });
}
```

And this is how I am trying to get the returned result:

```
function getActivity() {
    jsonData = activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail)
}
```

However, `jsonData` is always `undefined` here (which I am assuming is because the async fetch call has not finished yet when attempting to assign the returned value to `jsonData`. How do I wait long enough for the data to be returned from the fetch call so that I can properly store it inside of `jsonData`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

always `return` the promises too if you want it to work:
- `checkUserHosting` should return a promise
- in your case it `return` a `promise` which `return` the result `data`.

```
function checkUserHosting(hostEmail, callback) {
    return fetch('http://localhost:3001/activities/' + hostEmail)
        .then((response) => { 
            return response.json().then((data) => {
                console.log(data);
                return data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            }) 
        });
}
```

and capture it inside .then() in your main code:

```
function getActivity() {
    let jsonData;
    activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail).then((data) => {
       jsonData = data;
    }        
}
```

EDIT:

Or even better, use the new syntax as @Senthil Balaji suggested:

```
const checkUserHosting = async (hostEmail, callback) => {
 let hostEmailData  = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/activities/${hostEmail}`)
 //use string literals
 let hostEmailJson = await hostEmailData.json();
 return hostEmailJson;
}

const getActivity = async () => {
 let jsonData = await activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail);
  //now you can directly use jsonData
}
```

Comment: When I try and do this, I am getting an error that says `Cannot read property of 'then' of undefined` on the line `activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail).then(function(data)`. Any idea what this might be and how to fix it?

Comment: did you used `return fetch(...` & `return response.json()...`?

Comment: I forgot to return the call to fetch()... thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Last example is returning a promise anyway, it suppose to return value instead a promise, I did await response.text() and returns another promise, I want the value alone, and this does not work at all.

Answer (score 5):

You're partially right. It's because you're trying to get the result of this asynchronous call in a synchronous fashion. The only way to do this is the same way you deal with any other promise. Via a `.then` callback. So for your snippet:

```
function getActivity() {
    return activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail).then((jsonData) => {
        // Do things with jsonData
    })
}
```

Any function that depends on an asynchronous operation must itself become asynchronous. So there's no escaping the use of `.then` for anything that requires the use of the `checkUserHosting` function.

Comment: Same as the answer from ET-CS. When I try and do this, I get an error that says `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Why is this happening?

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, return your promise from `checUserHosting`, eg `return fetch...`

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of new ES6 and Es7 syntax and what others have written is also correct, but this can be more readable and clean,

you are trying to get aysnc value synchronously, here `jsonData` will be undefined because, you move to next line of execution before async function(checkUserHosting) is finish executing, this can be written as follows

```
const getActivity = async () => {
 let jsonData = await activitiesActions.checkUserHosting(theEmail);
  //now you can directly use jsonData
}
```

and you can write `checkUserHosting` in a different using new syntax like this

```
const checkUserHosting = async (hostEmail, callback) => {
 let hostEmailData  = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/activities/${hostEmail}`)
 //use string literals
 let hostEmailJson = await hostEmailData.json();
 return hostEmailJson;
}
```