# Using Fetch response in a if statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, http, fetch

I have a fetch function that takes a URL and gives out the response.

```
public getHTTPResponse(URL : string) {
    fetch(URL).then(function(response) {
        return response;
    })
}
```

I try to use the response in a IF-statement.

For example if the response is `200` it should be true. So far I have:

```
if (this.getHTTPResponse(item.ListUrl) === )
```

Where `item.ListUrl` is a link. I can't get my head around on what I should have on the right side of the operator to test if the response is `200` (or any other for that matter). Any help?

Comment: You can't do anything on the right hand side; getHTTPResponse doesn't currently return anything, and if it did comparing promise equality rarely makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get data returned from fetch() promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604040/how-to-get-data-returned-from-fetch-promise)

Comment: Can you post your success and failure response here so we can see what type of response it's returning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `response` object has a property `status` which value is an integer. Try like that:

```
  fetch(URL)
   .then(function(response) {
      if(response.status === 200) {
         // do something
       };
     })
```