# Fetch request error while I can see the good result in the browser dev tool

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I need to fetch JSON data from a localhost server using JS.

The fetch request throws an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

It looks like the answer is empty, but when I open the browser dev tool I can see the JSON data in the network section.

```
fetch(url, init)
 .then(res => res.json()) //return the error

fetch(url, init)
 .then(res => res.text()) //return an empty string
```

The result I can see in the network section is well formatted and when I copy/paste it to manually use `JSON.parse()` I get the right result.

Comment: See if there are CORS errors in the console  - if not show an example of the JSON and

Comment: I guess there are some hidden warnings in the backends output. Take a look at the raw message you receive and you will find the problem

Comment: Most likely your backend does not returning a valid JSON. Sometimes this happens if your url is not correct and backend or proxy returns a default not found html page. Try to inspect the request in developers tools in browser to see what response you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the promise and than wait:

```
const method = async() =>{
    return fetch(url, init)
     .then(res => res.json())
     .catch(err)=>{
       //manage error here
    }
}
```

than you do :

```
method().then(res=>....)
```

For more info look here : [How to get data returned from fetch() promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47604040/how-to-get-data-returned-from-fetch-promise)

Comment: Thx, check my answer I probably didn't put it in the right place sorry